# CSS and HTML: padding, border-spacing or border-collapse won't work on a table

Tags: html, css, spacing

I Decided to remove the table for now and just use DIVS. (UPDATE)

This is a continuing personal program I'm trying out. I am learning as I go with html and css. I was wondering why no matter what I try to do to create space between each row in the table it doesn't change. I tried border-spacing... border-collapse... padding yet nothing happens.

The table is on the left hand side of the page.

CSS:

```
tr.spaceUnder > td
    {
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      display: block
    }

    table {
        border-spacing: 10px;
        border-collapse: separate;

    }

    td {
        padding: 20px;
    }

/* Formating for left sidebar of information  */
    #sidebar {

    "background-color: #eee;
    height: 200px;
    width:350px;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

Html code

```
<div id ="sidebar">

                <table style = "width:350px; height: auto;">
                <tr class = "spaceUnder">

                <td>
                <div><b> Things to take into account: </b></div>
                <div>
                <p>
                When creating a website, don't forget about structuring.
                If you can't get the objects to stop moving then your logic
                must be wrong.
                </p>
                </div>
                </td>
                </tr>

                <tr class = "spaceUnder">
                <div><b> Things to take into account: </b></div>
                <div>
                <p>
                When creating a website, don't forget about structuring.
                If you can't get the objects to stop moving then your logic
                must be wrong.
                </p>
                </div>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>

        </div> <!-- end sidebar -->
```

[image]

FYI-The middle container of text should be under the right ones. -This will be my next question because I've been trying to fix that for hours too.

Comment: It looks like there is also a little typo in your CSS: `"background-color: #eee;` has a " at the start of it.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth... I would recommend you learn building web layouts with Divs and CSS instead of Tables.  Tables for layouts is a very dated way of building the web and it wont be doing you any justice.  It's like learning to drive a car in a [Model T](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_xEdRg-6CKJM/TA_s7Em4KFI/AAAAAAAAAGw/B5iiBM1IQns/s1600/model-t.gif). It may seem daunting at first (we've all been there) but you will be surprised how quickly you'll begin to wrap your head around it.  Plus we're here to help! :)

Comment: State clearly what the problem is. “Won’t work” is not a problem description. Do not include screenshots that do not actually correspond to the code shown.

Comment: Ok thanks for showing me my typo. I will fix that and see what happens. I will see if there is a better way then tables once I try some of the examples. I didn't have a table at first but the spacing wasn't working either which is why I resulted in choosing a table.

Comment: Jukka K. Korpela: the image I showed is exactly connected to my code. I said the code involved the box on the left in my first paragraph of words in my question. So I am confused why you said I wasn't clear. I said the spacing commands wouldn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer try this css below

```
tr.spaceUnder > td
    {
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      display: block
    }

    table {
        border-style: solid;
        border-spacing: 10px;
        border-collapse: separate;
        margin-top: 120px;

    }

    td {
        padding: 20px;
    }

/* Formating for left sidebar of information  */
    #sidebar {

    "background-color: #eee;
    height: 200px;
    width:350px;
    float:left;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7ot44m0e/)

you just have to add `border-style` and `margin-top` to separate the two rows

hope this sweets your need

Comment: This didn't work. I don't know why my table won't work and I am wondering if its due to the css code or html

Comment: I will see if my next table will work and will reference this if errors arise. I appreciate your help :)